# What's causing "BoxConstraints forces an infinite width" in this Flutter code?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignupPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SignupPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Center(
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  margin:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(top: 160.0, left: 70.0, right: 70.0),
                  child: const Text(
                    'Sign up',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Ephesis',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 25.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 18.0, right: 18.0),
                  child: const Text(
                    'Wishes, deliver the wishes to your loved ones',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 12.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontFamily: 'Ephesis',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 30.0,
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: const TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    filled: true,
                    labelText: 'Username',
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      maxWidth: 300.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
// spacer
              const SizedBox(height: 12.0),
// [Password]
              Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: const TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    filled: true,
                    labelText: 'Password',
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      maxWidth: 300.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  obscureText: true,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                child: Divider(
                  height: 70.0,
                  thickness: 1.0,
                  indent: 20.0,
                  endIndent: 20.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              Card(
                elevation: 7.0,
                color: Colors.white,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: const [
                    ListTile(
                      minLeadingWidth: 6.0,
                      leading: Icon(
                        Icons.people_alt_rounded,
                      ),
                      title: Text(
                        'Sign up with apple',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 10.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit and put your code in the coding box to make it readable

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with the code you posted, in terms of layout hierarchy. The one that's causing the immediate problem is in the `child` your `Card` widget. You currently have: `Card` > `Row` > `ListTile`.

You should **remove the `Row` widget**, so it becomes `Card` > `ListTile`, and it will fix the crash for you.

However, there are other areas of improvement, for example, you have a `Column` widget being the only child of a `ListView` etc. I recommend you take a look at the basics of how Flutter Layout works. You can start with this official doc: [Understanding constraints](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints).